# Any chance of maths.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, url

Maybe this seems like a peculiar thing to ask, but out of curiosity, is it possible to link the URL `maths.stackexchange.com` to the current `math.stackexchange.com` site?

As an Australian, it's "maths" not "math".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We have added the alias - it will be active after our next deployment.

Comment: Wow!  That's really cool (:

Comment: I checked, maths.se works for me. meta.maths.se does not though, but that is minor I suppose :-)

Comment: Seemed overkill to alias the meta since it's a link from the parent site.

Comment: I agree it is overkill, just wanted to let you know the situation, in case you did actually do it.

Answer (score 14):

We'll look at this, as a redirect synonym for the URL.